# How is this question classed as 'an answer'?

Tags: support, flagging, disputed-flags

I recently flagged [this](https://superuser.com/a/769136/316136) question as 'not an answer', but it has been disputed.

[image]

I understand that this is a user who wants to help (as said in their last line), but I don't understand the reason it is 'an answer'...?

*Now,* he has enough rep to put this 'answer' in a comment...

Could anyone tell me what classifies this as 'an answer'? So I don't flag real 'answers' again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This flag was not handled by a member of the moderation team but was dismissed as a [result of passing through](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/243968) the Low Quality review queue. I believe this happens simultaneously to your flag being presented to moderators but it appears that the review was completed before a moderator saw your flag.

At the time you flagged the item the user was below the threshold for posting comments but they have the power now.  I would generally try to show a bit of leniency with this kind of post and give it some time, with an expectation that it is soon to be edited into an answer.  In this case that has not happened so it is most certainly flag-fodder.

Please do continue to flag answers like this.  If they are simply asking for clarification and providing no possible solution then they are, as you point out, a comment rather than an answer.

I have dealt with the post for now.

For future reference if a flag is marked as "disputed" then it was declined with the involvement of normal community members, if it is "declined" then a moderator was involved.

Comment: 1. So the Low Quality Review Queue is automatic - the answer was put there automatically? 2. I'm guessing it isn't possible to remove the '1 disputed` in my flagged posts in my profile now...? It looked good with everything 'deemed helpful' ;). I'll remember the difference between disputed and declined now - thanks!

Comment: No worries, glad to help :).  Yes, the answer would appear to have entered the review queue automatically as a result of your flag.  As to the "1 disputed" there is nothing we can do, though at the very least it does not show up on your normal user profile as a red count next to your flag count, it's just a "dead" flag, so there's that.

Comment: OK and OK, I thought it came on my profile ;). Thanks again!

Comment: Just another question - for the future, should I have just asked this in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator? Or was this the right place?

Comment: Either is fine by me. Doing so here will bring it to the attention of more users and so will highlight that people may not be reviewing correctly and that they may want to pay a bit more attention when working the review queues. But if you do feel that you would rather be a bit more casual and discrete then chat is most certainly an option.  For chat keep in mind that moderator activity is sporadic so we may not get back to you immediately. Alternatively flagging again is a potential option... whichever method you are most comfortable with really.

Comment: OK Thanks (again) :)